# Text-wrapping and enumerated list in a table

Tags: tables

I currently am trying to type a table in  LaTeX, such that I need not only text-wrapping in one of the cells, but also an enumerated list in one cell. Here is what I have, but the table slides off the page at present:

```
\begin{table}[lh]
\begin{tabular}{|c||p{3cm}|p{9cm}|c|}
\hline
& \textbf{Root Position} & \textbf{First Inversion} & \textbf{Second Inversion} \\
\hline
\textbf{Major/minor triad} & 
    \begin{enumerate}
    \item Double the Root
    \item Double the $5^{th}$ 
    \item Double the $3^{rd}$
    \end{enumerate}
&  Double any pitches \textbf{except} tendency tones (\^{4}, \& \^{7}) 
                    &  Double the $5^{th}$ \\
\hline 
Diminished triad & Double the $3^{rd}$ & Double the $3^{rd}$ & Double the $5^{th}$ \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

How can I prevent the 'run-off' here? Thanks.

Comment: Some possible options: you could use `resizebox` from the `graphicx` package, or make it into a `sidewaystable`

Comment: Your column widht specification are too large for your page - Your two `p{}` columns add up to 12cm!! Try `{|@{}p{2.1cm}||p{2.5cm}|p{3cm}|c|@{}}` and see if that is any better.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image]

You need to choose your column widths such they fit, `9cm` is rather a lot. Also your MWE had an illegal table option `[lh]` best to use no option or `[htp]` if you want to allow `h`.

This isn't really pretty enough but it may get you started, you just need to experiment with widths, font size and `\raggedright` or `\centering` where appropriate.

```
\documentclass{article}



\begin{document}


\noindent X\dotfill X

\noindent X\dotfill X

\centering\small
\begin{tabular}{|p{2.2cm}||p{2.5cm}|p{2cm}|c|}
\hline
& \textbf{Root Position} & \textbf{First Inversion} & \textbf{Second Inversion} \\
\hline
\textbf{Major/minor triad} & 
\setlength\leftmargini{10pt}
    \begin{enumerate}
    \item Double the Root
    \item Double the $5^{th}$ 
    \item Double the $3^{rd}$
    \end{enumerate}
& \raggedright
 Double any pitches \textbf{except} tendency tones (\^{4}, \& \^{7}) 
                    &  Double the $5^{th}$ \\
\hline 
\centering
Diminished triad & Double the $3^{rd}$ & Double the $3^{rd}$ & Double the $5^{th}$ \\
\hline
\end{tabular}

\noindent X\dotfill X

\end{document}
```